# C++ and currying

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, currying

I've the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

auto fn = ([](int x){
       return [x](int y) {
          return x * y;
       };
});

int main() {

    int i = fn(2)(4); // 8

    cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine. 
However, I want to call a second function later like:

```
auto i = fn(2);

i(4); //error: 'i' cannot be used as a function
```

Are there any way to call the last function later and then bind with the first call?

Comment: Did you mean auto i = fn(2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works as expected

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

auto fn = [](int x){
       return [x](int y) {
          return x * y;
       };
  };

int main() {

    auto i = fn(2)(4); // 8
    cout << i << endl;
    auto j = fn(2);
    cout << j(4) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**ADD**

By the way gcc 4.5 with -std=c++0x gives the following error if you use int instead of auto:

```
currying.cpp:17:17: error: cannot convert ‘<lambda(int)>::<lambda(int)>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
currying.cpp:19:16: error: ‘j’ cannot be used as a function
```

which is an "obvious" and useful information to get what's going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The result of `fn` is not an integer, so you cannot assign `fn(2)` to an integer (don't even know why that compiles).

You should be able to do `auto i = fn(2);`

Comment: indeed, it does not compile. At least with g++

Comment: I mean of course that `int i = fn(2);` does not compile, `auto i = fn(2)` does; I am using g++ 4.5, but it is strange that  4.7 compiles without warning `int i = fn(2)`, since `fn(2)` it's not int

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
int main() {
    auto i = fn(2);
    cout << i(4) << endl;  // prints 8
    return 0;
}
```